# MongoDb 4.2 update with aggregation pipeline from normal update with nested array element selection

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, python-3.8

I try to write update with aggregation pipeline but I do not know how to do it (I need conditional updates apart this simple update - I simply example). I try many variants but it still not work. I want to update element is one element of nested array matched with 'judge_id'.

How to do this update with pipeline syntax (I need it for conditional updates)?

```
position.update_one(
    filter={'position': 1,
            'scores.judge_id': 1},
    update={'$set': {'scores.$.evaluation': 10}},
)
```

I get such results from classic update:

```
# original data -> it is O.K. always :)
{'position': 1, 'scores': [{'judge_id': 1, 'evaluation': 1}, {'judge_id': 2, 'evaluation': 2}]}

# it is classic update with use $ operator -> it is O.K. judge_id==1 updated!
{'position': 1, 'scores': [{'judge_id': 1, 'evaluation': 10}, {'judge_id': 2, 'evaluation': 2}]}
```

But with update with aggregation pipeline - I can not achieve same.

```
# now I trying pipeline update #1 -> INVALID both evaluation is updated not judge_id==1
# how to select only one element!
{'position': 1, 'scores': [{'judge_id': 1, 'evaluation': 10}, {'judge_id': 2, 'evaluation': 10}]}

# now I trying pipeline update #2 -> INVALID strange results both updated again with full tables.
# if/then/else not works like I think
{'_id': ObjectId('5ef4f432f342e09a163bc921'), 'position': 1, 'scores': [{'judge_id': 1, 'evaluation': [10, 10]}, {'judge_id': 2, 'evaluation': [10, 10]}], 'score': {'0': {'evaluation': 10}}}
```

Here is full code and data.

```
import pymongo

client = pymongo.MongoClient()
client.drop_database('delete_it')
db = client.delete_it
db.position.create_index('position', unique=True)

position: pymongo.collection.Collection = db.position
position.insert_one(
    document={'position': 1,
              'scores': [{'judge_id': 1, 'evaluation': 1},
                         {'judge_id': 2, 'evaluation': 2}]}
)

r = position.find_one(
    filter={'position': 1},
    projection={'_id': False}
)

print(r)

position.update_one(
    filter={'position': 1,
            'scores.judge_id': 1},
    update={'$set': {'scores.$.evaluation': 10}},
)

r = position.find_one(
    filter={'position': 1},
    projection={'_id': False}
)

print(r)


position.update_one(
    filter={'position': 1,
            'scores.judge_id': 1},
    update=[{'$set': {'scores.evaluation': 10}}],
)

r = position.find_one(
    filter={'position': 1},
    projection={'_id': False}
)

print(r)

# conditional update
position.update_one(
    filter={'position': 1,
            'scores.judge_id': 1},
    update=[
        {'$set': {'scores.evaluation': {'$cond': {
            'if': {'$eq': ['$scores.judge_id', 1]},
            'then': 10,
            'else': '$scores.evaluation'
        }}}}
    ],

)

r = position.find_one(
    filter={'position': 1},
    projection={'_id': False}
)

print(r)
```

I found this solution first. It is little slower than `concatArrays`.

```
    position.update_one(
        filter={'position': 1,
                'scores.judge_id': 1},
        update=[
            {
                '$set': {
                    'scores': {
                        '$map': {
                            'input': '$scores',
                            'in': {
                                '$mergeObjects': [
                                    '$$this', {
                                        'evaluation': {
                                            '$cond': {
                                                'if': {'$eq': ['$$this.judge_id', 1]},
                                                'then': NEW_EVALUATION,
                                                'else': '$$this.evaluation'
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
    )
```

I found second solution which is faster.

```
    position.update_one(
        filter={'position': 1,
                'scores.judge_id': 1},
        update=[
            {
                '$set': {
                    'scores': {
                        '$concatArrays': [
                            {
                                # change evaluation of one element
                                '$map': {
                                    # array with one element only matching
                                    'input': {
                                        '$filter': {
                                            'input': '$scores',
                                            'cond': {'$eq': ['$$this.judge_id', 1]}
                                        }
                                    },
                                    'in': {
                                        '$mergeObjects' : [
                                            '$$this', {'evaluation': 10}
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            # array of rest elements not matching
                            {
                                '$filter': {
                                    'input': '$scores',
                                    'cond': {'$ne': ['$$this.judge_id', 1]}
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
    )
```

Comment: Agg pipeline supports $out and $merge stages, what do you mean by updating in an agg pipeline?

Comment: I mean `position.update_one(
    filter={'position': 1,
            'scores.judge_id': 1},
    update=[{'$set': {'scores.evaluation': 10}}],
)` as update with aggregation pipeline. I refer to https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/.

Comment: Okay, can you express your requirements in prose? What are you trying to update when?

Comment: In prose: I want use update with pipeline syntax. I want to update one object on scores array which have judge_id=1 by set evaluation to 10 (other objects in scores should be not changed. In classic syntax update={} it will be `position.update_one(filter={'position': 1,  'scores.judge_id': 1}, update={'$set': {'scores.$.evaluation': 10}},)` but how to do same in pipeline syntax - I have no idea? `position.update_one(filter={'position': 1, 'scores.judge_id': 1}, update=[{'$set': {???}}],)`. I need pipeline syntax to do this for conditional updates.

Comment: @D.SM I found some solution but it is very ugly - maybe fast :) See: `condition = {'$cond': {'if': {'$eq': ['$$this.judge_id', 1]},
                       'then': 20,
                       'else': '$$this.evaluation'}}
position.update_one(
    filter={'position': 1,
            'scores.judge_id': 1},
    update=[{'$set': {'scores': {'$map': {'input': '$scores',
                                          'in': {'$mergeObjects': ['$$this', {'evaluation': condition}]}}}}}],
)` notice I am using condition variable to simplify query syntax.

Comment: I can't make the positional update operator work and I don't think it is supported going by this documentation quote: "arrayFilters is not available for updates that use an aggregation pipeline.". I think the query and update, when using the agg pipeline, are independent. But I inquiried as to how this is supposed to work.

Answer (score 1):

Aggregation pipeline does not support positional update syntax.

I am told another way of doing something similar is with `$concatArrays` but I have not investigated exact details of this approach.

Comment: Aggregation pipeline does not support positional update syntax. That is why this question so it is not answer. I know that before asking question :)

Comment: I've been told using $concatArrays is another way of achieving the desired behavior but I wasn't given details.

Comment: I appreciate you engagement. BTW I tested `$concatArrays` it is slower than `$mergeObjects` - it is again intuition but speed test show such results. I try to randomize data to check if it because same data or because it is faster (no updates is possible). I can not score it as answer.

Comment: Looks that I do mistake in speed test `$concatArrays` is faster! Little but faster than '$mergeObjects` as should be.

Answer (score -1):

Aggregation is not created to change data, but only to receive. You can create a snapshot of the data using the aggregation in the desired form (for example, an array of document identifiers that satisfy or do not satisfy your condition), and then process them with the forEach operator or another iterator available to your language. I am not familiar with python, but here is a javascript example.

Well, that’s what you want. But this is not the right approach, it too complicates the development. If your object inside the scores array contained an identifier, this would greatly simplify the process. Otherwise, it is necessary to deal with the substitution of field names directly in the pipeline. The bottom line is that you must first expand the array into an object, then change it and return it to its original state.

```
db.getCollection("test").aggregate(
// Pipeline
[
    // Stage 1
    {
        "$match": {
            "scores.judge_id":1
        }
    },
    // Stage 2 (convert array to object)
    {
        "$project":{
            "_id": "$_id",
            "position": "$position",
            "scores": {
                "$arrayToObject": {
                    "$reduce":{
                        "input": "$scores",
                        "initialValue": [],
                        "in": {
                            "$concatArrays": [
                                "$$value",
                                [{
                                    "k": {
                                        "$toString": "$$this.judge_id"
                                    }, 
                                    "v": "$$this.evaluation"
                                }]
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    // Stage 3 (update evaluation)
    {
        "$set": {
            "scores.1": 10
        }
    },
    // Stage 4 (convert object to array)
    {
        "$project":{
            "_id": "$_id",
            "position": "$position",
            "scores": {
                "$objectToArray": "$scores"
            }
        }
    },
    // Stage 5 (return the name of the fields)
    {
        "$project":{
            "_id": "$_id",
            "position": "$position",
            "scores": {
                "$reduce":{
                    "input": "$scores",
                    "initialValue": [],
                    "in": {
                        "$concatArrays": [
                            "$$value",
                            [{
                                "judge_id": {
                                    "$toDouble": "$$this.k"
                                }, 
                                "evaluation": "$$this.v"
                            }]
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
);
```

Comment: Mongodb since 4.2 allow pipeline in update. I do not want use `aggregate` but `update` but not really known how to construct query. I refer to https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/.

Comment: As aggregate solution is good but will it work with update - I think problem will be with match since it is not supported in such queries. See: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/.